# Debian 10 Unable to install vim, terminator

Tags: debian, terminal, vim

Today I noticed that Debian 10 is released, however, I am unable to install terminator and vim as the packages are not found. sources.list was set to cdrom, but I changed it to network http://deb.debian.org/debian/ and commented cdrom.

Here is my sources.list content:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 2$

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 2$

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

any thoughts

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only added the plain URL, then your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is invalid.

An example `sources.list` for buster with the `main`, `contrib` and `non-free` repositories would be:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim terminator
```

as root.

See https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added the content of my sources.list to the original post, however I am still unable to install vim and terminator.

Comment: You forgot to add the first line `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free`

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, the original sources.list is as follows:

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

I should comment `deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main` line, also uncomment the last two lines, this is not enough, before `buster-updates` I should add `buster`, thanks to @Freddy for this tip, later on I noticed that the cdrom line contains `buster`:

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ buster contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster buster-updates main contrib
```